# Does grid.reconfigure removes all existing function/event handlers present in columns and create new table?

Tags: extjs

Does grid.reconfigure removes all existing function/event handlers present in the columns and create a new table?

I have tried both

```
 grid.reconfigure([
```

and

```
Ext.define('GridStore', {
```

but existing event handlers are gone.

What is the best solution to change the below view:

[image]

TO this view:
[image]

Comment: if both grid are complex, i would use 2 grids panels and hide/ show as needed

Comment: Please give some more details on HOW you're reconfiguring your grid.
If you pass a new column configuration array, it will obviously use that instead of the old one.

Comment: Where do you define your listeners that are "gone"?